# Compiler Optimization: const on non-pointer function arguments in C

Tags: c, compiler-construction, constants, compiler-optimization

Modern compilers can optimize code when they see a `const`. **However, I've never seen the C standard library use `const` for its non-pointer arguments.** For example `memcmp()` is an example of this. It has 2 `const void *` arguments, but its third argument is `size_t`.

Why is the standard library (and other libraries) designed this way? Why don't I see `const size_t` or `const int` in modern code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those `const`s mean different things.  In

```
int memcmp ( const void * ptr1, const void * ptr2, size_t num );
```

`const void * ptr1` means that `memcmp` will treat `ptr1` as *pointing to constant data* and won't modify it; similarly for `const void * ptr2`.  Thus, the caller knows that the stored values won't be changed and can optimize accordingly.  In a function call like

```
int result = memcmp(ptr1, ptr2, num);
```

the variables `ptr1`, `ptr2`, and `num` are *copied* into the function.  `memcmp` makes no promises not to adjust them; it only promises not to adjust what the pointers point to.  Indeed, it might increment/decrement any of the copied variables in order to step through the arrays if that proves efficient.  If it wanted to promise not to change any of them, the declaration would be:

```
int memcmp ( const void *const ptr1, const void *const ptr2, const size_t num );
```

For simple data types (like pointers and integers), little (if any) optimization can be gained in this way, and the original specifiers of this function (and others) apparently saw no reason to prevent implementations from modifying the variables in fortuitous circumstances.

Answer (score 7):

C uses call-by-value. It does not help the compiler one bit to mark a function argument as `const` (note that none of the arguments of `memcmp()` is `const`. The pointers arguments could also be declared `const`, and you could have suggested that they should be: `int memcmp(const void * const s1, const void * const s2, size_t const n);`. But they aren't).

The reason it would not help the compiler to mark function arguments `const` is that a function argument is just, from the point of view of the function, a local variable. As long as the function does not take its address, it's very easy for the compiler to see that the variable is never modified.

In contrast, the `const` modifiers that are part of `memcmp()`'s prototype (`const void *s1`)
 are part of its contract: they express that the function does not modify the pointed data. The `const` modifier is never used this way for the argument themselves because the caller does not care if the function modify its arguments: they are just copies (again because C uses call-by-value).

Comment: My Linux manpage says that `memcmp()` does have `const` pointers.

Comment: @dongle26 It says `const void *`, right? That's ”pointer to const“. The pointer is not const.

Answer (score 0):

Main reason for this is Library consistency. Changing a `size_t` argument to a `const size_t` will require libraries that do modify the size to be rewritten. Not all implementations of a library need to use the same algorithm. This is the main reason why existing library functions are not being adapted.

New library functions are often created purposefully with non `const` arguments so that certain machine dependent implementations can use the modifiable argument.

For instance the Intel C++ Compiler version of `memcmp` actually counts down the `length` argument during execution. Some other implementations may not do so.

Comment: No, your answer makes not much sense. Setting value parameters of functions to `const` buys you nothing.

Comment: It does. If the compiler decides to inline a function then const arguments are not copied.

Comment: If a mondern compiler inlines a functions, it does constant propagation, regardless of whether or not the argument is `const`-qualified. The only thing that a `const` parameter imposes on the *definition* of the function is that you can't change it inside the function. For the *declaration* it doesn't make any difference.